# How to Convert (0.ABBA)16 hexadecimal into octal?

Tags: binary, hex, boolean-logic, octal

How to convert this ,
I m not getting this?
I tried converting  that into decimal 10*16^-1 and so on and got this (0.6708068848)10
Now it become really a complex task is there any short method to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating it; I find it easiest to first convert it to binary (base-2) and then to octal (base-8).

Binary (bits partitioned into 3's because octal numbers have 3 bits):

```
0.101_010_111_011_101_000
```

Octal:

```
0.527350
```